# Creating an Azure SQL federation sharded off last digit of INT/LONGINT?

Tags: azure-sql-database, federation, federated-table

Let say a table has a primary key (`CustId`) of type `int` or `longint`. We would like to shard this table into a federated table depending on whether the `OrderId` is odd or even. i.e.

Federated 'primary key' = `(Fed_key, CustId)` where `OrderId` is of type `int` or `longint` and `Fed_key` = `0` if CustId==even, `1` if CustId==odd.

For example:

```
CustId = 1234 => Federated 'primary key' = (0,1234) 

CustId = 6789 => Federated 'primary key' = (1,6789)
```

This basically gives us 2 federation members (aka partitions). Later on we may group Fed_key into (1,3,5), (2,4,6) and (7,8,9,0) for additional partitions. We don't think we'll need over 5 partitions.

***Question***: How do I express the above logic to Azure SQL? I guess it would need to be done during federation creation or federated table creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we went from INT/LONGINT identity to GUIDs/ uniqueidentifiers for the non-sharded primary key. The GUIDs are created in the application tier. Within the application tier itself, we pick the last nibble of the guid and decide the partitionId.

Now the `PartitionId, CustId` is the Federation wide primary key and the application presents this to the database tier during any transaction. This has been tested to work.

Answer (score 0):

from the docs([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597469.aspx)):

> The federation column cannot be a persisted or non-persisted computed column.

besides, assuming a customer has multiple orders, do you really want to query x number of federation members to get all the orders?

Comment: You are right, I noted the wrong column. Long day. It's sharded over CustId.